# CSS Files served from https Domain instead of CDN domain

Tags: 7, domain-access, caching, cdn, ssl

I setup a Drupal site on two domains (www.example.com and blog.example.com); I am using the Domain module.

I also setup a fake cdn.example.com domain on the same DOCUMENT_ROOT folder; I am using the CDN module for this.

I setup boost for static page cache with aggregation and minimalization of CSS and JavaScript files.

At first, everything was right and the files were served correctly from cdn.example.com. After some time (I don't know how long), something changed. The boost cache files referring to the CSS and JavaScript files are served not via http://cdn.example.com, but https:/blog.example.org (note the https instead of http). Since my blog.example.org does not have a SSL certificate, the files won't get requested and my style is broken.
When I flush the cache, everything works again.

I updated the modules and Drupal core to the latest stable production versions.

Why do I have this behavior?

Comment: You have CDN, Domain and Boost fighting for precedence. Boost should be least of a problem, but consider asking authors if CDN and Domain are supposed to work together. And are you using secure pages or other ssl enabler?

Comment: I don't use 'secure pages'

Comment: OK, so it seems a deeper mystery than I thought it is. [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) and [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) gave me similar problems in the past, but if that's not your case, I'm sorry I can't help you.